# Process user-inputted conditions (==, &&) inside app

Tags: ios, swift

I have the task, and I can understand how to deal with it (in what direction I need to start). Application need to understand user-inputted condition like that:

```
((VAR1 != 1 && VAR2 == 2) OR (VAR3 != 1 && VAR4 == 2)) AND (VAR5 = 2)
```

I have that variables inside my database, so it's no problem to replace VAR1 with real data. How in what way I can process that condition inside application. I thought about separating full condition to little blocks, but I don't understand yet how to separate, there is no symbol that I can split string.

So can you help in what direction I need to start working to process such conditions in Swift app?

Comment: You will require a parser to be able to handle this kind of input. As far as I know there is not one out there yet for Swift that would be widely accepted.

Comment: There are some classes in `Foundation` that could be used for this probably, e.g. `NSPredicate`, `NSExpression`. The question is a bit too broad though.

Comment: @Sulthan, you saved my life, NSPredicate is exact thing what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Sulthan, `NSPredicate` is solution.

```
let expressionString = "((1 == 1) or (1 == 2)) and (1 == 2)"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: expressionString)
print(predicate.evaluateWithObject(nil))

// Output: false
```